# Erro em transição de telas tkinter

Tags: tkinter

Ola sou novo no python e estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação que tem acesso ao dblite3,
consegui adicionar uma outra tela mais quando faço uma conexão com o meu db ele volta para tela inicial,
queria que ele focasse só em uma tela e voltasse para a tela inicial só quando fosse fechado.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from datetime import datetime
from tkinter import messagebox
import sqlite3


conn = sqlite3.connect("C:\sheepDown\BaseDate\dbsheep.db")
c = conn.cursor()

result = c.execute("SELECT MAX(idp) from produtos")
for rec in result:
    idp = rec[0]



now = datetime.now()

datatual = now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")

class inicio:
    def __init__(self, primeiro):
        self.primeiro = primeiro

        self.primeiro_ph = PhotoImage(file="prime.gif")
        self.lab = Label(primeiro, image=self.primeiro_ph)
        self.lab.place(x=400, y=100)




        self.btn_inicio = Button(primeiro, text="INICIO", width=30, bg='LawnGreen', fg='white', font='arial 10', command=self. pri_jan)
        self.btn_inicio.place(x=190, y=20)

        self.btn_pend = Button(primeiro, text="PENDENCIAS", width=30, bg='red', fg='white',  font='arial 10')
        self.btn_pend.place(x=530, y=20)

        self.btn_cad = Button(primeiro, text="CADASTROS", width=30, bg='DeepSkyBlue', fg='white', font='arial 10', command=self.new_jan)
        self.btn_cad.place(x=870, y=20)

        self.list = Listbox(primeiro, width=32, height=1)
        self.list.insert(0, )
        self.list.place(x=550, y=490)
        self.list.insert(END, "DATA E HORA : " + str(datatual))
#JANELA============CADASTROS

    def new_jan(self):


        cad = Tk()
        self.clab = Label(cad, text="CADASTRO DE PRODUTOS", font=('arial 30 bold '), fg='black')
        self.clab.place(x=400, y=0)
        cad.geometry('1366x768+0+0')

        self.texb = Text(cad, width=60, height=30, )
        self.texb.place(x=700, y=148)
        self.texb.insert(END, "DATA E HORA DO ULTIMO PRODUTO: " + str(datatual))

        self.nomepr = Label(cad, text="NOME", font=('arial 17 bold'), fg='black')
        self.nomepr.place(x=15, y=150)
        self.nomepr['bg'] = 'LightCyan'

        self.nomepr_e = Entry(cad, width=20, font=('arial 15 '))
        self.nomepr_e.place(x=300, y=150)

        self.valorp = Label(cad, text="VALOR", font=('arial 17 bold'), fg='black')
        self.valorp.place(x=15, y=290)
        self.valorp['bg'] = 'LightCyan'

        self.valorpr_e = Entry(cad, width=8, font=('arial 15 '))
        self.valorpr_e.place(x=300, y=300)

        self.quantidade = Label(cad, text="QUANTIDADE", font=('arial 17 bold'), fg='black')
        self.quantidade.place(x=15, y=220)
        self.quantidade['bg'] = 'LightCyan'

        self.quantidade_e = Entry(cad, width=8, font=('arial 15 '))
        self.quantidade_e.place(x=300, y=220)

        self.btn_adc = Button(cad, text="Cadastrar", width=15, bg='steelblue', fg='white', command=self.getcli_items)
        self.btn_adc.place(x=300, y=400)

        self.btn_clear = Button(cad, text="Limpar", width=15, bg='Firebrick1', fg='white', command=self.limp_cli)
        self.btn_clear.place(x=470, y=400)

    def getcli_items(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.nomepr = self.nomepr_e.get()
        self.valorpr = self.valorpr_e.get()
        self.quantidade = self.quantidade_e.get()

        if self.nomepr == '' or self.quantidade == '' or self.valorpr == '':
            messagebox.showinfo(title='PRIME-TI', message='PREENCHA TODOS OS CAMPOS')

        else:
            sql = "INSERT INTO produtos (nomepr, valorpr, quantidade) VALUES (?,?,?)"
            c.execute(sql, (self.nomepr, self.valorpr, self.quantidade))

            self.texb.insert(END, "\n\nO PRODUTO  " + str(self.nomepr) + " FOI CADASTRADO NO BANCO DE DADOS ")

            messagebox.showinfo(title='PRIME-TI',
                                message='PRODUTO : ' + str(self.nomepr) + '\n\nNO VALOR DE R$: ' + str(
                                    self.valorpr) + '\n\nNA QUANTIDADE DE : ' + str(self.quantidade))



    def limp_cli(self, *args, **kwargs):

        self.nomepr_e.delete(0, END)
        self.valorpr_e.delete(0, END)
        self.quantidade_e.delete(0, END)
```

Comment: Você poderia tentar ser um pouco mais claro?

Answer (score 0):

Aconselho a não usar Tkinter e sim o PySide2.
O PySide2 possui Qt5 com o Qt Designer, uma IDE de criação de Interface Gráfica do Usuário do tipo arrastar e soltar.

```
Acesse o site: https://pypi.org/project/PySide2/
```

Para instalar basta abrir o prompt de comando como administrador colar o seguinte código, apertar Enter e esperar o download e instalação.

```
pip install PySide2
```

Depois de instalado procure pelo "designer.exe" dentro da pasta do Python.